# I want to add some string in Last Line of File using Java, but i am getting stuck , Need help :)

Tags: java, file, io

This is my code:

```
import java.io.File;    
import java.io.FileWriter;    
import java.io.BufferedWriter;    
import java.io.IOException;    

public class Append    
{    
    public static void main( String[] args )    
    {       
        try{    
            String data = " Thank you very much";    

            File file =new File(" ");    

            //if file doesnt exists, then create it    
            if(!file.exists()){    
                file.createNewFile();    
                System.out.println("New File Created Now");    
            }    

            //true = append file    
                FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);        
                BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);            
                bufferWritter.write(data);    
                bufferWritter.close();    

            System.out.println("Done");    

        }catch(IOException e){    
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }    
    }    
}
```

In above code i am trying to add "String data = " Thanks you very much"; " in G://Openone.txt, but its not wokrking correctly, and i am not getting the output.

Comment: Is the file path left empty intentionally? Seems like that could be a starting point. When you say is it not working correctly, could you elaborate? Is it crashing? No file generated? Incorrect contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main( String[] args )    
{       
    try{    
        String data = " Thank you very much";    

        File file =new File(" ");    

        //if file doesnt exists, then create it    
        if(!file.exists()){    
            file.createNewFile();    
            System.out.println("New File Created Now");    
        }    

        //true = append file    
            FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file,true);        
            BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
            bufferWritter.write(data);
            bufferWritter.close();
            fileWritter.close();

        System.out.println("Done");    

    }catch(Exception e){    
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }    
}
```

Use file object instead of `file.getName()` in following line.

```
FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        File file =new File(" ");
```

should become

```
        File file = new File("G:\\Openone.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 7+, you can use:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("G:\\Openone.txt"), "Thank you very much".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

BTW, I recommend you to refactor your code in order to manage the exception properly with a finally block, because if an exception is throw in write line the close method will not be called.